# Cannot get image from node server public/image folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I created a node server public/image folder to store my image file uploads. I can upload to the folder and store the url in the postgresql table with that users id with no problem. However, when I fetch that image url from the the database, I get the url but the browser always says "cannot get /...". Im using react to fetch the json response and add the image url property to the src in an avatar. Please help. I don't understand why. I'm using the app.use middelware below:

`app.use(express.static('public')) app.use('/images', express.static('images'))`

[This is the image in the folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVAIH.png)

[This is the avatar where I add the src props.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMWDc.png)

[Here is the URL inside the browser react tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUjrA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you're getting a CORS error, you should use this:

```
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

you can access it with you're specified port:

```
http://localhost:PORT/filenameWithExtension
```